# REXML in Ruby (use of XML in Ruby)

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby. What I want to know is what's the use of XML in Ruby? I mean for what purpose REXML is there in Ruby? Could anybody give me example like by adding some XML documents in our Ruby program? We have this kind of benefit. It means I want to know for what purpose XML is used in Ruby. Sorry if it looks stupid question, but I want to know.

Comment: REXML is used to parse and generate XML. If you don't know what to do with XML, then maybe you don't need to use REXML? XML is a text representation of data. Some programs use XML to store their configuration. Some web services also use XML as their data interchange format (SOAP is XML-based for example). Try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML for more info.

Comment: Most of your questions are very basic and already have been answered elsewhere. If you want to pick up ruby, I suggest you check the online book ["Programming Ruby"](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) or ["Why's (poignant) Guide to Ruby"](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/)

Answer (score 2):

The XML is use in ruby like in other langage. You can use it to configure your programme or communicate with other stuff.

After we prefere JSON to communicate ad YAML to configure.

Comment: thanks shingara but cud u plzz explain how xml is used to communicate with other stuff and what r possible other stuff ??

Comment: like webservice.

By REST or even by SOAP. Not specific to ruby